# Upload multiple photos symfony2

Tags: image, symfony, controller, upload, syntax-error

I followed the following tutorial: https://symfonytricksandcheats.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/subir-multiples-ficheros-a-la-vez/

And after following it returns the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/miweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:436
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
thrown
```

I do not quite understand, what I've seen is that the error is in the controller, which is:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $album = new Album();
        $form = $this->createForm(new AlbumType(), $album);
        **$form->handleRequest($request);**

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            // Handle the uploaded images
            $files = $form->getData()->getPicture();

     ...
```

If I delete the code that is in bold it does not give me this error, it gives me another one different, but it is the only code that if I remove it changes the error that shows me.

Twig:

```
            
                {{ form_label(form.name) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
            
            
                {{ form_label(form.picture) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.picture, { 'full_name': 'simplex_album[picture]' ~ '[]' } ) }}
            

            {% if error is defined %}
                
                    {% for errorMessage in error %}
                        {{ errorMessage }}
                    {% endfor %}
                
            {% endif %} 
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: Please share your twig / html template and codes below `$files = $form->getData()->getPicture();` if you have.

Comment: Explain a contents of [Error](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.error.php) object. Class Error is available only from PHP 7.x and old versions of Symfony components do not support it. Thats because why you see this error instead of real problem description. You need to update framework, downgrade PHP version or just debug/var_dump Error object.